# Remove temp file and confirm upload in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, file-upload, drupal-7

I've got two issues.

1) When I'm testing my file upload, I upload the same file over and over. But drupal is adding a incremental number at the end of each file. Which is fine, but I'd rather just override the old file. Should I use another method apart from `file_copy()`? I know drupal is keeping an internal reference to all the files uploaded. I don't need drupal to keep a reference on my behalf.

2) I'm adding the file names to a database (with my own additional information), if the filename already exists how can I write:

```
if (file_exists) {
 confirmation('do you still want to upload this file?');
 // if yes foo_file_submit($form, &$form_state, 'confirmed');
} else {
 foo_file_submit($form, &$form_state);
}
```

What I have so far

```
function foo_file_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    //'file_validate_is_image' => array(), // Validates file is really an image.
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg'), // Validate extensions.
  ));
  // If the file passed validation:
  if ($file) {

    // Prepare the file to upload
    $filepath = 'public://foo/files';
    file_prepare_directory($filepath, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY); // Create the folder if it doesn't exist

    // Move the file, into the Drupal file system
    if ($file = file_copy($file, $filepath)) {
      // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
      $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file to the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite existing files, you can pass a third parameter when calling the `file_copy` function.

By default, Drupal uses `FILE_EXISTS_RENAME` which appends `_{incrementing number}` until the filename is unique.

In your case it would be:

```
file_copy($file, $filepath, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)
```

If you are adding already uploade files in your custom table (filename), why not executing a query on filename to verify if it exists? Or you could use same logic as Drupal does:

```
$uri = 'public://yourfile.docx';
if (file_exists($uri)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. But how can I get return confirm_form() if the file exists? I've tried adding it in the validation function but I can't get it to work.